# What is the difference between invariance to translation, covariance to translation and equivariance to translation?

Tags: convolution, computer-vision, signal-processing

I get stuck at understanding the difference between invariance to translation, covariance to translation and equivariance to translation in the context of of convolutional neural network.

What does it mean :

1. Convolution is equivariant to translation ?
2. Convolution is convariant to translation ?

What is the difference between covariance and equivariance ?

3. Are convolutional layers equivariant to translation ?

Comment: Does this come from any source? If so which? – *Reviewer*

Comment: https://aboveintelligent.com/ml-cnn-translation-equivariance-and-invariance-da12e8ab7049 and and https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03393 . I get confused at understanding the difference between covariance and equivariance

Answer (score 5):

There are two schools of thought when it comes to definitin of equivariance, covariance, invariance, and same-equivariance.

- **Covariance** is a concept often used in physics and is the same term as **equivariance**. Both are used when applying the transformation $\pi$ on the input of the function $f$ can be achieved by appying another transformation $\psi$ on the output of the function:
  $f(\pi(x))=\psi(f(x))$
- **Same-equivariance** is an especial case of equivariance when $\psi=\pi$ (in some literature, **same-equivariance** is termed as **equivariance**, and instead, **equivariance** is termed **covariance**):
  $f(\pi(x))=\pi(f(x))$
- **Invariance** is another especial case when the transformation $\psi$ is the identity function ($\psi=\mathbb{1}$)
  $f(\pi(x))=f(x)$

Based on the above definitions:

- convolution is "equivariant" to translation
- convolution is also "same-equivariant" to translation,
- and since covariance is just another term for the same concept, convolution is "covariant" to translation.

Same is true for convolutional layers.

Comment: In two of your last three bullets, you said "convolution is equivariant to translation" twice; did you mean something else one of those times?

Comment: Thank you @xFioraMstr18. Fixed now.